# Very stuck on ADT packaging and AIR native extensions on iOS

Tags: ios, air

So I am using the native extension from http://blog.aboutme.be/2011/12/10/udp-in-air-for-ios-using-a-native-ex tension/

It comes with a flex demo app that works perfectly on Android and iOS when built in FB. I made a small as3 app in FB and that works perfect on Android and iOS as well.

I then took the app.xml from the as3 FB project and used it for my flash pro/adt project. I built the package in adt with the following

Android:

start adt -package -target apk -storetype pkcs12 -keystore androidTest.p12 NetPRO_Demo.apk NetPRO_Demo-app.xml NetPRO_Demo.swf 72icon.png -extdir extensions

iOS:

start adt -package -target ipa-ad-hoc -storetype pkcs12 -keystore Certificates.p12 -provisioning-profile CashRegisteriPad1.mobileprovision NetPRO_Demo.ipa NetPRO_Demo-app.xml NetPRO_Demo.swf 72icon.png -extdir extensions

The Android version works perfectly, the iOS version sits at a black screen and freezes. I have spent days on this, what is wrong in my ADT packaging that is different from FB packaging that it breaks only on iOS.

Also, if I get rid of native extensions, my ADT packaging works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - my extension worked OK on Android, and iOS in ipa-test, but froze on launch with ipa-ad-hoc.

The fix was link to the NativeExtension swc on iOS as an external library. From the command line I had to modify my config.xml file supplied to the compiler as follows:

BEFORE:

```
<flex-config>
<swf-version>14</swf-version>
<target-player>11.2</target-player>
    <compiler>
        <headless-server>true</headless-server>
        <source-path>
            <path-element>src</path-element>
            <path-element>..</path-element>
        </source-path>
        <library-path>
            <path-element>../Extensions/ExampleExt/bin/iOSExampleExtension.swc</path-element>
            <path-element>${flexlib}/libs/air/airglobal.swc</path-element>
             <path-element>${flexlib}/libs/framework.swc</path-element>
        </library-path>
    </compiler>
</flex-config>
```

AFTER:

```
<flex-config>
<swf-version>14</swf-version>
<target-player>11.2</target-player>
    <compiler>
        <headless-server>true</headless-server>
        <source-path>
            <path-element>src</path-element>
            <path-element>..</path-element>
        </source-path>
        <external-library-path>
            <path-element>../Extensions/Telephony_iOS/bin/iOSTelephonyExtension.swc</path-element>
        </external-library-path>
        <library-path>
            <path-element>${flexlib}/libs/air/airglobal.swc</path-element>
             <path-element>${flexlib}/libs/framework.swc</path-element>
        </library-path>
    </compiler>
</flex-config>
```

Hopefully this will fix your problem too OP.

Comment: so how did you create swc? just renaming ane's?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be missing a parameter -C before the remaining files. try:

`start adt -package -target ipa-ad-hoc -storetype pkcs12 -keystore Certificates.p12 -provisioning-profile CashRegisteriPad1.mobileprovision NetPRO_Demo.ipa NetPRO_Demo-app.xml -C  NetPRO_Demo.swf 72icon.png -extdir extensions`

if that doesnt solve it, i'd bet your provisonal profile isnt for distribution and you're trying to package it for ad-hoc. maybe try a different profile or change the packaging to `ipa-debug-interpreter`. 
also, does it ask for the password? maybe add `-storepass *yourpass*` and iphone sdk too `-platformsdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/`